# Does smalltalk and it's rails-like framework have something similar to auto loading?

Tags: smalltalk, autoload, seaside

By autoloading I mean the way rails loads classes as described in
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Does the documentation say it does?

Comment: Can you explain why you are looking for this in Smalltalk? What problem do you have that would be solved by this feature? (imho, this has everything to do with Ruby and is not applicable in a Smalltalk setting).

Answer (score 2):

My expectation is that while something like this could be developed for
Smalltalk, Smaltalk's image based development model means that it isn't
really appropriate.  During development you want the classes loaded so
you can browse / inspect them, and after deployment the classes are
saved as part of the Smalltalk image, not loaded one by one from files.

As Max noted below, my comments above don't hold for GNU smalltalk, and I don't know enough about it to comment further.

(It would be nice if the people down-voting the question gave a reason)

Comment: Keep in mind that not all dialects are image based (e.g. GNU Smalltalk).